# Trinidad API usage caused an exception on weblogic managed server in my case

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic11g

I faced an exception when I try to deploy to new created managedServer (which applied JRF).
When application wants to use org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/model/ChildPropertyTreeModel class, occured exception below. That was used to be run properly on WC_Spaces.
Even if I copied the trinidad-api, trinidad-api-impl.jar libraries into domainhome/lib folder, nothing changes.

What might be the reason?

```
oracle.adf.controller.activity.ActivityLogicException: ADFC-06015: An exception occured when invoking a task flow initializer.
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.util.Utils.createAndLogActivityLogicException(Utils.java:230)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeInitializer(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:709)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.enterTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:625)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeLocalTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:337)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:229)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:217)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ChildViewPortContextImpl.invokeTaskFlow(ChildViewPortContextImpl.java:104)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState.createChildViewPort(ControllerState.java:1387)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.ControllerContextImpl.createChildViewPort(ControllerContextImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.createRegionViewPortContext(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:474)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.getViewPort(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:392)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.doProcessBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:164)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.processBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:112)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.doRegionRefresh(TaskFlowRegionController.java:241)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.refreshRegion(TaskFlowRegionController.java:119)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3204)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2876)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.doRegionRefresh(TaskFlowRegionController.java:270)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.refreshRegion(TaskFlowRegionController.java:119)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3204)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2876)
        at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareRender(PageLifecycleImpl.java:561)
        at oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.FacesPageLifecycle.prepareRender(FacesPageLifecycle.java:82)
        at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$9.execute(Lifecycle.java:224)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.access$1000(ADFPhaseListener.java:23)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$5.before(ADFPhaseListener.java:402)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.beforePhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:64)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.beforePhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:44)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:352)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:222)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/model/ChildPropertyTreeModel
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
...
```

Comment: And i realized that when i deploy to managedServer through Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6 it says "Removing the following prohibited entry from the EAR: lib/trinidad-api. Removing the following prohibited entry from the EAR: lib/trinidad-impl.jar" while packaging the ear file. That may cause the problem, i can not supply build operation to make not remove those 2 libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a custom class extended ChildPropertyTreeModel and implements Serializable. 
I ve made it Serialized with SerializedTreeModel. And this class was in another project(structure) in another word war deployment package's web-inf/lib has contained this class. After i replaced the SerializedTreeModel class location into the same package with refered project, eventually solved the problem. I could not understand the magic honestly.

```
public class SerializedTreeModel extends ChildPropertyTreeModel implements Serializable
{
    public SerializedTreeModel(Object dataList, String dataChild)
    {
        super(dataList, dataChild);
    }
}
```